# Understanding Trap Detection

Tags: pathfinder-2e, traps

Could anyone explain me the following entry:

> Stealth DC 17 (trained)

Is it right that I need to be trained in Perception for this but I do not roll perception but a Seek check? Do I have to on guard for this?

What if there is

> Stealth DC 17

so without a proficiency rank?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Detecting Hazards

The rules for detecting hazards are on page 520. You want the second paragraph under the "Detecting a Hazard" heading:

> ... If the hazard doesn't list a minimum proficiency rank, roll a secret Perception check against the hazard's Stealth DC for each PC. For hazards with a minimum proficiency rank, roll only if someone is actively searching (using the Search activity while exploring or the Seek action in an encounter), and only if they have the listed proficiency rank or higher.

So in short:

- For hazards with no minimum proficiency: no specific actions are required. All PCs are entitled to the free Perception check regardless what their level of proficiency is and whether they are looking or not.
- For hazards with a minimum proficiency: The Seek action (in combat) or Search activity (in exploration mode) are required to detect a trap. PCs must also have at least the minimum proficiency.
- The GM then rolls a Perception check in secret.

### Search, Seek, and Perception

> Is it right that ... I do not roll perception but a Seek check?

There are no Seek or Search checks. Seek and Search are choices the player makes which prompts the GM to make a secret Perception check. It's still a Perception check.

Seek is an action, which is used in combat (Core Rulebook, pg. 471). When a character spends an action to Seek, the GM makes a secret Perception role on their behalf.

Search is an exploration activity (Core Rulebook, pg.480). Searching is a kind of shorthand for using the Seek action repeatedly. The GM makes a secret Perception roll on the player's behalf, as per the Seek rules.

### Your examples

> Stealth DC 17

Every PC, regardless of their Perception proficiency, are entitled to the secret Perception check. They *do not* need to be Seeking (in combat) or Searching (exploration mode) for the secret check to occur.

> Stealth DC 17 (trained)

PCs who have at least trained proficiency in Perception are entitled to the secret Perception check. However, they must be Seeking (in combat) or Searching (exploration mode) for the secret check to occur.

Comment: It may be worth noting that all characters are at least Trained in Perception... or maybe not. I'm not sure

Comment: @Ifusaso I don't think it adds anything to this answer, but I posted it as a new question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196995/can-a-pc-be-untrained-in-perception

Comment: Your answer is incorrect about the "Stealth DC 17" check. ["**They automatically receive a check to detect hazards** *unless the hazards require a minimum proficiency rank to do so.*"](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=669) and "**For hazards with a minimum proficiency rank**, roll only if someone is actively searching (using the Search activity while exploring or the Seek action in an encounter), and only if they have the listed proficiency rank or higher." As it lacks a minimum proficiency rank, you don't need to be using a particular action to find that hazard, you automatically roll.

Comment: Essentially, actions only matter if the hazard has a minimum proficiency rank to identify/find it.

Comment: @willuwontu You are absolutely right, thanks. It's even right there in the quote! I've edited it in.