# Can a PC be untrained in Perception?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, traps

Hazards require a secret Perception check to notice them:

> For hazards with a minimum proficiency rank, roll only if someone is actively searching (using the Search activity while exploring or the Seek action in an encounter), and only if they have the listed proficiency rank or higher. (*CRB, 520*)

Many hazards explicitly require Trained proficiency. An example includes the Poisoned Lock:

> **Stealth:** DC 17 (trained)

It seems like all PCs would be trained (or better) in Perception at level 1. Is it possible for a PC to be untrained in Perception? I'm open to the possibility that this would either be a static condition (they haven't become proficient somehow) or a temporary condition (perhaps imposed by a spell, magic item, etc.).

Answer (score 12):

## All characters are trained in perception

Th core rules say on page 448

> Nearly all creatures **are at least trained in Perception**, so you will almost always add a proficiency bonus to your Perception modifier (...) Circumstance penalties to Perception occur when an environment or situation (such as fog) hampers your senses, while status penalties typically come from conditions, spells, and magic effects that foil the senses

So even in negative circumstances, you will still be trained, just applying a penalty.

The variant rules in the Gamemastery Guide says under **initial proficiencies**

> A level 0 character is trained in Perception, all saving throws, unarmed attacks, unarmored defense, and one simple weapon of their choice

Adding further support that any character should be trained in perception by level 1.

Comment: It could be worth mentioning that the likely reason for requiring a minimum perception rank of "trained", which everyone possesses, is to ensure that the trap must be actively searched for rather than passively detected.